# Properties on a Class Not Changing

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

Ok, I've got 2 classes.

One with all the properties and one with all the methods.

In the class with all the methods I call this.

```
    switch (_allProperties.switchNumber) {
    case 0:
        CCLOG(@"Saving Info");
        CCLOG(@"FirstNumber = %d",numberA);
        CCLOG(@"SecondNumber = %d",numberB);
        //I get the correct numbers on the dbg
        _allProperties.firstNumber = numberA;
        _allProperties.secondNumber = numberB;

        CCLOG(@"Properties.FirstNumber = %d",_allProperties.firstNumber);
        CCLOG(@"Properties.SecondNumber = %d",_allProperties.secondNumber);
        //Im getting 0 on both of this logs.
        break;
```

So, here's the way I call for the _allProperties on allMethods Class

```
           @property (strong) PropertiesClass *allProperties;
```

And Here's how the .FirstNumber && .SecondNumber are cast on PropertiesClass

```
         @property (nonatomic, assign) int firstNumber;
         @property (nonatomic,assign) int secondNumber;
```

What am I missing? Why isn't the property getting the value??

Thanks for your time, have  a good day people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see, you still declare property of PropertiesClass and don't alloc and init this class.
Before using _allProperties,  you should alloc and init it by: _allProperties = [[PropertiesClass alloc]init];

Comment: I did:
 _allProperties = [[PropertiesClass alloc] init];

in the init method of allMethods, nevermind I also initialized it on the method Im doing the switch and it worked. :D